# Repeat WindowBuilder JLabel using Grid Layout

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I want to repeat a JLabel "n" no. of times where "n" is given by user.
This implementation, using WindowBuilder's Grid layout, doesn't work, prints nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
JLabel lblNewLabel_1[]=new JLabel[20];
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1[] = new GridBagConstraints[20];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
        lblNewLabel_1[i] = new JLabel("Table #");
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i].insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i].gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i].gridy = 4+i;
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1[i], gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i]);
}
```

Full Method, my content pane is grid layout.

```
private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 507, 432);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{57, 377, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{60, 37, 35, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setToolTipText("Max: 20");
        textField.setText("0");

        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(arg0.getSource()==textField)
                    n = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getActionCommand());

            }
        });

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter The Number of Tables");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 3;
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1[] = new GridBagConstraints[20];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            lblNewLabel_1[i] = new JLabel("Table #");
            gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i].insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i].gridx = 0;
            gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i].gridy = 4+i;
            frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1[i], gbc_lblNewLabel_1[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Grid layout hasn't Insets and GridBagConstraints

Answer (score 0):

The default layout for a JFrame is a `BorderLayout`.

If you want to use a `GridBagLayout` then you need to set the layout of the content pane to use a GridBagLayout.

I suggest you read the section from the Swing turial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more explanation and working examples.

If you want to use a `GridLayout`, then you also need to set the layout manager of the content pane to a GridLayout and you don't use any constraints. Again, read the tutorial for examples.

Comment: Thanks for responding . My ContentPane is gridBagLayout. Updated question to reflect full method.

Comment: @IshaanGarg, I've never use the GridBagLayout with the columnWidths, rowHeight... properties. I also don't create new contraints every time I add a component to the panel. Try looking at the Swing tutorial for working examples. The code you posted doesn't help because it is not a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @IshaanGarg, I don't know why you switched to GroupLayout. That was designed to be used by IDE's. A GridBagLayout is far easier to use. All you need to do is read the tutorial and test the examples to understand how it works.